Python insert image into cell
How can I use python code to insert an image (local file) into an excel cell.
In the Excel UI https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-picture-in-cell-in-excel-e9317aee-4294-49a3-875c-9dd95845bab0 there is a insert picture to cell function.
However, from the API I have only been able to:

add any image (but not into a cell)
anchor with a cell - but not inside the cell
visually fine-tune the image size/cell size to then overlay the image over a cell (but not into)

How can I replicate the Insert a Picture in a Cell from the python API?
I want to write a pandas dataframe of the following structure to an excel:
key,value,image_path
foo,bar,my_image.png
bafoo,123,awesome.png

however in Airtyble style (like their attachments feature) I want ti display/visualize the image attachment directly from excel.
This is possible from the UI - so far I could not find any python API for this.
clarifications
commonly something like:
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
#ws.merge_cells('A1:A3')
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(FILENAME)
row_number = 1
col_idx = 1
cell = ws.cell(row=row_number, column=col_idx)
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('output.xlsx')

is suggested - but this is just adding the image - not adding it into/iside the cell
I also do not want to add an image URL - just link the file as can be accomplished from the UI
edit
I would not want to unzip the XML and manually (or via python) edit the XML ideally.
edit2:
it must work with the unzip the XML and add it manually to XML. I have been exploring with some AI tools, in fact some images are now loaded into the cells - but excel complains about unreadable data. However, when clicking ignore/delete it can load the image into the cell. I now need to figure out how to write the correct XML for XLSX by hand.
Hopefully though there is a better way via some API.

Do you have a version of Excel that supports 'Picture in Cell'? If not then it cannot be done.

sure. I do have that version.

So far I have hand-cooked something which is manually editing the XML - it is not yet fully working - excel is complaining a bit but rendering the data

is there a better way?
